# Complex Numbers - Finding values when both are equal

Tags: complex-numbers

The question :  Find values for $a$ and $b$ given that: $$(a + bi)(2 + i) = a - 3i$$
I've expanded the brackets to give me: $$2a + ai + 2bi + bi^2 = a - 3i$$

and from there to get $$2a + ai + 2bi - b = a - 3i$$

and using only reals to get $$2a - b = a$$

and therefore $$a = b$$
But how do find values for either if they equal each other? Wouldn't the answer be any number or would it just be $-1$, if so, why?

Comment: $(a+b)(2+i)=2a+ai+2b+bi$. Should the original equation read: $(a+bi)(2+i)=a-3i$?

Comment: @Dave Yes, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also compare the imaginary part.

That is $$ai+2bi=-3i$$

and obtain

$$a+2b=-3$$

Combining with what you found, i.e.

$$a=b$$

Solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Ah yes! Sorry I had completely forgotten, thank you

Comment: I think there is a typo, should it be $a+bi$ in the first  equation?